# How to add Mosaico.io email template builder to PHP application

Tags: php, mosaico

I have came across this email template editor/builder called [Mosaico](https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico) which i would like to integrate with my PHP application. I'm having difficulties installing it as the documentation doesn't seem to cover the installation process very well, would be great if someone could suggest what am i missing and how to install **Mosaico** for a **PHP project**.

I have done so far:

1. Installed NodeJS v8.0 + added PHP ImageMagick extension
2. npm install
3. installed grunt-cli globally
   npm install -g grunt-cli

**Now the manual says:**
compile and run a local webserver (http://127.0.0.1:9006) with incremental build and livereload

grunt

So i run this "grunt" command and it comes with an error saying "grunt hasn't been installed locally to your project" however i have installed grunt-cli to be available globally:
[image]

4. Next I have copied all the files from the [git directory](https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico) to root directory on my server except index.html and edit.html
5. run the command "npm install" to install all required dependencies.
6. running the command "grunt" works now however it has stopped responding on:

Running "watch" task

Waiting...

[image]

**What am i missing here?**

## UPDATE 1

I have found what i was doing wrong. The configuration file holding all the path variables needed changing. Everything started working as it should after that.
In my case it was located here:
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/backend-php/config.php"